# "Mass Email Contacts" in custom page

Tags: apex, visualforce, contact, standard-objects

The question is can we use this standard "Mass Email Contacts" action in visual force page?
I want just feed it with Contacts/ContactsIds from visualforce Page as criteria for picks contacts to list are too complex for standard list viev....
Did anyone did it? Examples would be great :)

Ps. And no, add it to campaign is not the solution for me ;)

Comment: Can you please share some details about the 'Mass Email Contacts' standard action? I am not sure if I know this feature.

Comment: On contact list view details you have link with this name.
I think it will be best if you check it yourself

Answer (score 1):

I happened to use a ready solution from developed by Deepak Anand which worked great for me. Its worth a shot.

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hJhuAAE

Cheers,
Amit

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a back-end custom field of type "checkbox" and populate this field for all the Contacts that you want to send the emails to. Your controller code can do this for you.
2. Once that is done, you can navigate to the "Mass Email Contacts" standard page from your VF page. The link to the standard page is "/ui/massmail/MassMailStageManager?setupid=MassMailFilter&ftype=C&wizardRetUrl=%2F003%2Fo".
3. Create a list view filtering out the records based on the custom field we created.
4. Proceed with the template selection and sending of emails.

I hope this will help.